# Does an Artificer (Artillerists) Eldritch Cannon provoke opportunity attacks?

Tags: dnd-5e, opportunity-attack, artificer

The rules for the eldritch cannon state:

> The cannon is a magical object. Regardless of size, the cannon has an AC of 18 and a number of hit points equal to five times your artificer level.

The rules for an opportunity attack state:

> You can make an opportunity attack when a hostile creature that you can see moves out of your reach.

Does this mean that an eldritch cannon cannot provoke opportunity attacks?